# TypeScript AngularJS 1 controller global variable value set from view reset on view reload

Tags: angularjs, typescript

For sorting table data by clicking header text (as anchor), I have a global variable in AngularJS1 TypeScript controller whose initial value is set in controller as a global variable to 'false' for ASC sort order. When the table header is clicked, the varibale's value is flipped to 'true' and 'false' alternatively for changing the sort order to DESC/ASC.

When the contoller's aysnc function with callback if called to fetch data again, the sort order is not retained what was set in the view instead the sort order defaults to 'false' which was set as a global variable in controller. I have tried to change the value manually in controller's async function (which returns a 'Promise' to fetch data) in the finally block which also didn't work as the variables value is set to the value 'false' as set in the globally. Due to this, the sort order is not flipped/changed regardless on how many times I click the table header.

AngularJS Typescript Controller code is as below:

```
    private sortReverse: boolean = false;  // global set the default sort order

    constructor(productService: inventory.Interfaces.IProductService) {
                this.productService = productService;
                this.getProductsByPage(this.pageNo);
            }
```

HTML/View code snippet is as below:

```
<table id="products" ng-cloak>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
            <th>
                <a href="#" ng-click="prdCtrl.sortType = 'Name'; prdCtrl.sortReverse = !prdCtrl.sortReverse; prdCtrl.getProductsByPage(prdCtrl.pageNo)">
                 Name
                </a>
            </th>
```

Controller is instantiated only once via route (and not in the view as):-

```
static configureRoutes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/home/", { controller: "inventory.controllers.productController", templateUrl: "/app/views/products.html", controllerAs: "prdCtrl" });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
```

Comment: Which routing mechanism your are using? ng-router or ui-router?
please share your code through plunker

Comment: ng-router - routing code already provided above.

Comment: Even without routing, by including the routed view's code in the parent view code causes the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the same boolean value in constructor also

```
export class ControllerName {
    private sortReverse: boolean = false;  // global set the default sort order
    constructor(productService: inventory.Interfaces.IProductService) {
                this.productService = productService;
                this.getProductsByPage(this.pageNo);
                this.sortReverse = false; //initialise same value on this
            }
}
```

Comment: I have previously tried the same by assigning the value in the constructor and even leaving the global variable value uninitialized and then initializing it in the controller but that didn't work. Also, I tried the same code logic in AngularJS1 without using typescript and it works fine.

Comment: When the view is reloaded, the global variable is again re-initialized to the default value whether the value is initialized globally or within constructor.

Comment: Which routing mechanism you are using? ng-router or ui-router ?

Comment: Even without routing, by including the routed view's code in the parent view code causes the same issue.